# NULL Reference when trying to get NameIdentifier Claim

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, adal

I modified the TodoSPA sample application on github to be a 1.0.0-rc1-update1 application since that is the platform we are developing with. I had to make changes to Startup but left the client code as is. The sample uses the OAuth2 implicit flow with the ADAL client library. When I click on the TodoList link, I authenticate against the authentication server and the client calls the Get method in the TodoListController class. So far, so good. The Get method does the following.

```
string owner = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
IEnumerable<Todo> currentUserToDos = db.Todoes.Where(a => a.Owner == owner);
```

FindFirst throws a null reference exception. Why don't I get a NameIdentifer claim? If I get all of the claims using ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims, I don’t see as many as I would expect. (Results from Visual Studio 2015 Watch Window.)

- Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
- [0] {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: }  System.Security.Claims.Claim
- [1] {http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: }    System.Security.Claims.Claim